# Chemfig: How do I Change the Angle of a Ring Attached to a Ring?

Tags: chemfig, angle

Essentially I just want to increase the angle between the two 5 member rings, say 10-20 degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setangleincrement{30}
\setatomsep{20pt}

\begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{*6(=-(*5(-@{N}N-[@{CB1}]=
        *5([@{CB2}]-
        (-[-3]Ph)(-[:-15]H)
        -N(-[1]H)---)
        --))=-=-)}
        \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Actual Output]
[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the angle after the alias. `[@{CB2}:25]` or `[@{CB2}1]` (i.e. fixed angle increment of "1 unit") will both work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setangleincrement{30}
\setatomsep{20pt}

\begin{center}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{*6(=-(*5(-@{N}N-[@{CB1}]=
        *5([@{CB2}:25]-(-[-3]Ph)(-[:-15]H)
        -N(-[1]H)---)
        --))=-=-)}
        \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]